# Create process 14001 .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

Currently I am struggling with a very annoying problem, namely when I deploy my .net 2.0 application on Windows XP (without any SP) I am receiving a CreateProcess error with error code 14001. When I looked in the event log, I noticed there is a problem with the syntax of manifest or policy file. 
I tried to find such file in the deployed folder but there isn't any config or manifest file. My application consists of 3 dlls and 1 exe. All are written in .net 2.0. Additionally I am using SqlCe 3.5 and database sdf file. 
If you have any hints which could solve the problem please share with me.

aaa... I am logged as Administrator in Windows XP.
BR Jarek

Comment: Copy/paste the *exact* text of the message you found in the Windows event log.

Comment: So, when I start the program I got 3 errors logged in the Event Viewer. 1. [SideBySide EventID 59 - Generate Activation Context ist für C:\Programme\Test\Test.exe fehlgeschlagen.] 2. [ SideBySide EventID 58 - Syntaxfehler in der Manifest- oder Richtliniendatei "C:\Programme\Test\Test.exe" in Zeile 3.] 3. [SideBySide EventID 61 - Syntaxfehler in Manifest- oder Richtliniendatei "C:\Programme\Test\Test.exe" in Zeile 3.] I hope it helps, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this problem, please check XML syntax or other kinds of errors in application/web config file.

Answer (score 0):

sqlce is .net 3.5 (according to [this](http://dotnetperls.com/sqlce)). Loading this into 2.0 might cause this issue.

Use fuslogwv to check assembly loading errors 
and use reflector to check if all your references are 2.0 assemblies or not

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am still trying to use he fuslogwv. When I have some information I will put them here. Regarding sqlce, the runtime .net framework is .net 2.0. I know this because 1. VS project is 2.0 and I use the sqlce as a reference 2. I double checked it in Reflector.